# Multiscale Image Printing with Canves Overlay in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, multiscaleimage

We have a system in which we have big plan images loading in multiscale deepzoom images like an image gallery.Images are usually of very high resolutions.

Users have the ability to draw shapes ect on selected deepzoom image.We are using a canves on deepzoom image and save all overlay shapes drwan along with their logical poistion in db.thus the drawn shapes auto sets their position as user pans in or pans out.

We need an automated solution so we can take the printout of all the plan images along with all overlay work done on each deepzoom image.

Currently we are doing this one by one i.e we use Grid,Multistage,Canvas.We load image in Multiscale image,then draw Canves then we use following code to same them in jpeg from Grid(ContentGrid)

```
SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveDlg.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg|*.jpg|*.jpeg|*.jpeg)";
                saveDlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg";
                if ((bool)saveDlg.ShowDialog())
                {
                    using (Stream fs = saveDlg.OpenFile())
                    {
                        SaveToFile(new WriteableBitmap(ContentGrid, null), fs);
                    }
                }
```

But this solution does not work properly.This throws memory issues when deepzoom image is big one.

We want something like this.For all plans images in gallery we need to loop and programatically convert to jpeg along with canves etc and then save to Amazon s3 by program.An automation will pick all the jpegs and make a single pdf for all those.

or an automated solution.

Please suggest.